# Redraw static text value after error form submitting

Tags: spring-mvc

I have just a simple HTML's plain text as parameter on my Spring **form**, e.g.

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="myObject">
    MyInput: 
    <form:input path="${myInput}" />
    <form:errors path="${myInput}" />
    <p>
    MyParam: {myParam}   <!-- WHAT SHOULD BE HERE? -->
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

I would like to redraw **{myParam}** value on the form that will be returned in case of some errors occurred on **MyInput** field. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @SessionAttribute("myParam") on controller is the answer here. Hope it will help some one.